# Create Dictionary of Words and Synonyms

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, wordnet

I'm a beginner in Python, and I have a dictionary of words as below:

```
thisdict ={  "Animal",  "Metal",  "Car"}
```

And I am getting their synsets as below:

```
syns = {w : [] for w in thisdict}
for k, v in syns.items():
    for synset in wordnet.synsets(k):
        for lemma in synset.lemmas():
            v.append(lemma.name())
            print(syns)
```

At the moment, the output of syns for Animal is:

```
 {'Animal': ['animal']}
 {'Animal': ['animal', 'animate_being']}
 {'Animal': ['animal', 'animate_being', 'beast']}
 {'Animal': ['animal', 'animate_being', 'beast', 'brute']}
 {'Animal': ['animal', 'animate_being', 'beast', 'brute', 'creature']}
 {'Animal': ['animal', 'animate_being', 'beast', 'brute', 'creature', 'fauna']}
{'Animal': ['animal', 'animate_being', 'beast', 'brute', 'creature', 'fauna', 'animal']}
{'Animal': ['animal', 'animate_being', 'beast', 'brute', 'creature', 'fauna', 'animal', 'carnal']}
{'Animal': ['animal', 'animate_being', 'beast', 'brute', 'creature', 'fauna', 'animal', 'carnal', 'fleshly']}
{'Animal': ['animal', 'animate_being', 'beast', 'brute', 'creature', 'fauna', 'animal', 'carnal', 'fleshly', 'sensual']}
```

My question is, is there a way to create a dictionary where each row contains a word and it's synonym, for example:

```
Animal: 'animal', 'animate_being', 'beast', 'brute', 'creature', 'fauna', 'animal', 'carnal', 'fleshly', 'sensual' 
Cat: ...
```

**EDIT**
Thanks to DannyMoshe, I've added if not key.lower() == lemma.name(): before the append and now have the following output:

```
['animate_being']
['animate_being', 'beast']
['animate_being', 'beast', 'brute']
['animate_being', 'beast', 'brute', 'creature']
['animate_being', 'beast', 'brute', 'creature', 'fauna']
['animate_being', 'beast', 'brute', 'creature', 'fauna', 'carnal']
['animate_being', 'beast', 'brute', 'creature', 'fauna', 'carnal', 'fleshly']
['animate_being', 'beast', 'brute', 'creature', 'fauna', 'carnal', 'fleshly', 'sensual']
```

Is there a way to select the last line, ['animate_being', 'beast', 'brute', 'creature', 'fauna', 'carnal', 'fleshly', 'sensual'], and match it to Animal in thisdict?

Comment: Isn't that what you have already created? Or am i misunderstanding what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to have a list of synonyms only, so animate_being, beast, etc. instead of {'Animal': ['animal', 'animate_being', 'beast', 'brute', 'creature', 'fauna', 'animal', 'carnal', 'fleshly', 'sensual']}. The idea is that I want to create a dictionary (or even a dataframe) where one column has a list of words and the next column has each word's synonyms displayed by row horizontally if that makes sense

Comment: So in the example you provide you want to remove animal from the list?

Comment: Yes, and only keep the last line that has all the synonyms which I want to match to Animal in thisdict.

Comment: So before you append, just add an if statement: `if not k.lower() == lema.name(): v.append(lemma.name())`. I think that should give you the desired output..

Comment: That works, but is there anyway to just use the last line of output instead of the whole text? I've updated my question.

Comment: What do you mean by "use"? In the example you are printing every iteration of the loop. If you want to print only the final value, place the print statement outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the complete answer you're looking for:

```
syns = {w : [] for w in thisdict}
for k, v in syns.items():
    for synset in wordnet.synsets(k):
        for lemma in synset.lemmas():
            if not k.lower() == lemma.name(): 
                syns[k].append(lemma.name())
print(syns['Animal'])
```

or if you just want the synonyms as a String:

```
print ' '.join(syns['Animal'])
```

Answer (score 2):

What's happening in your code is you are printing the `sysn` after you add each element because your print statement is inside all the for loops which leads to the printing `sysn` each time you add the element.

To get the output as u need the print statement should be outside of all the loops so that print statement will print after completing of adding the elements

```
thisdict = {"Animal","Metal","Car"}
syns = {w : [] for w in thisdict}
for k, v in syns.items():
   for synset in wordnet.synsets(k):
       for lemma in synset.lemmas():
           v.append(lemma.name())
print(syns)
```

Comment: Hello welcome to SO, can you give a brief description of how your answer is supposed to help OP?

Comment: @JamesWong-ReinstateMonica sure i will add the explanation now